# How to remove / delete nth element of a list

Tags: list

**Q:**  How to remove / delete nth element of a list.

**CAVEAT**:  Do **not** remove all occurrences / members matching nth element -- e.g., `eq` or `equal`.

**EXAMPLE**:  Remove the 17th element of:

```
'(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
```

**nth ELEMENT -- CHEAT SHEET / LEGEND**:

```
element 0:   a
element 1:   b
element 2:   c
element 3:   d
element 4:   e
element 5:   f
element 6:   g
element 7:   h
element 8:   i
element 9:   j
element 10:  k
element 11:  l
element 12:  m
element 13:  n
element 14:  o
element 15:  p
element 16:  q
element 17:  r
element 18:  s
element 19:  t
element 20:  u
element 21:  v
element 22:  w
element 23:  x
element 24:  y
element 25:  z
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, here's a destructive version I'd be happy with:

```lisp
(defun remove-nth-element (nth list)
  (if (zerop nth) (cdr list)
    (let ((last (nthcdr (1- nth) list)))
      (setcdr last (cddr last))
      list)))

(remove-nth-element 0 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(2 3 4 5)

(remove-nth-element 1 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(1 3 4 5)

(remove-nth-element 2 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(1 2 4 5)

(remove-nth-element 3 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(1 2 3 5)

(remove-nth-element 4 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(1 2 3 4)

(remove-nth-element 5 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

`setcar` returns NEWCAR, which is an uninterned symbol `G<N>` deleted with `delq`:

```el
(let ((l '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)))
  (delq (setcar (nthcdr 5 l) (gensym)) l)) ;⇒ (1 2 3 4 5 7)
```

You may also use `nil` for example as NEWCAR when there are no nil values in the list.

Comment: Neat trick. Using `(cons nil nil)` is a bit cheaper than `gensym` since you don't actually need a symbol here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple function to remove the nth element from a list:

```el
(defun remove-nth (n list)
  "Remove the nth element of a list."
  (if (> n (length list))
      list
    (append (cl-subseq list 0 n)
            (cl-subseq list (1+ n)))))

(setq test-list '(a b c d e))
(remove-nth 3 test-list)                ; => (a b c e)
```

Two notes: it requires `cl-lib`, and it's not terribly efficient,
as it walks through the list a few times.  The latter is probably
only noticeable for long lists.

Here are destructive and non-destructive versions that don't
require `cl-lib` (again, not terribly efficient):

```el
(defun delete-nth (n list)
  "Delete the nth element of a list (destructive)."
  (if (>= n (length list))
      list
    (setf (nthcdr n list) (nthcdr (1+ n) list))))

(defun remove-nth (n list)
  "Remove the nth element of a list."
  (if (>= n (length list))
      list
    (let ((list (copy-tree list)))
      (setf (nthcdr n list) (nthcdr (1+ n) list))
      list)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative answer which helps teach us how to `cl-subseq` from the `cl-lib` library.

Comment: You beat me with the `nthcdr`-way;-). Did only see it on the second glance. Deleted my answer...

Answer (score 3):

Here is another non-destructive version which uses `cl-loop`:

```el
(defun remove-nth-element (nth list)
  "Return a copy of a LIST, with NTH element removed."
  (loop for i in list
        for idx from 0
        unless (= idx nth)
        collect i))
     ⇒ remove-nth-element

(remove-nth-element 0 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
     ⇒ (2 3 4 5)

(remove-nth-element 1 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
     ⇒ (1 3 4 5)

(remove-nth-element 2 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
     ⇒ (1 2 4 5)

(remove-nth-element 3 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
     ⇒ (1 2 3 5)

(remove-nth-element 4 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
     ⇒ (1 2 3 4)

(remove-nth-element 5 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
     ⇒ (1 2 3 4 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer using just recursion. First we check to see if the list is empty, in which case we return the empty list. Then we check to see if we are removing the 0<sup>th</sup> element of the list, in which case all we want is the `cdr` of the list. If we haven't hit one of those base cases, we recur by removing the n-1<sup>th</sup> element of the `cdr` of the list, and then `cons` the `car` of the original list onto the result from the recursive call.

Should be very efficient. Runs in linear time.

```
(defun remove-nth-element (nth list)
  (cond
   ((equal nil list) list)
   ((zerop nth) (cdr list))
   (t (cons (car list)
            (remove-nth-element (- nth 1)
                                (cdr list))))))

;; Examples:
(remove-nth-element 5 '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
  ;; '(0 1 2 3 4 6 7)
(remove-nth-element 9 '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
  ;; '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
(remove-nth-element 0 '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
  ;; '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
```

Comment: This makes n recursive calls (hence uses linear stack space), so I doubt "very efficient" is a good description. And it runs the danger of stack overflow for big n.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised to see `cl-delete/remove-if` wasn't mentioned:

```el
(require 'cl-lib)
(defun delete-nth (nth list) ; Destructive version.
  (cl-delete-if (lambda (_) t) list :start nth :end (1+ nth)))
(defun remove-nth (nth list)
  (cl-remove-if (lambda (_) t) list :start nth :end (1+ nth)))
```

This is linear time, and should be reasonably efficient, though I expect marginally slower than than [wvxvw's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29791/5296) as it goes through some more generic codepaths.

Answer (score 1):

I was not happy with the accepted answer because it doesn't seem to 
be destructive for nth = 0. I came up with the following:

Non destructive version:

```el
(defun remove-nth-element (num lst)
  (append (seq-take lst num) (seq-drop lst (1+ num))))
```

`seq.el` functions are new in emacs 25.1. In older versions you may need to

```el
(require 'seq)
```

Destructive version, even for nth = 0:

```el
(defun delete-nth-element (num lst)
  (if (zerop num)
      (setf (car lst) (cadr lst)
            (cdr lst) (cddr lst))
    (pop (nthcdr num lst))))
```

Comment: When manipulating Lisp strings "destructive" usually means "is allowed to mess up the input list as it sees fit".  It doesn't *force* the input list to be modified.  You seem to want an operation that's performed "in-place" (i.e. it does not return the answer but instead just modifies its argument), but `delete-nth-element` *cannot* work "in-place" in the case where `num` is 0 and `lst` is a list of a single element.

Comment: @Stefan: Thank you for your observation. Indeed `delete-nth-element` doesn't just delete a single element but rather replaces it with `nil`, ending up with `(nil)` instead of expected `()`. +1.